# Lost password on parity! I do have the recovery 12-word phrases thankfully

Tags: recovery

[image]I was going to transfer all my SAN tokens from parity to another exchange site only to find out I’ve lost my long password. I was traveling for 4 months so I’m pretty sure i left it in one of the hotels I stayed at. However, I did find my 12-word recovery phrases in my phone and now I’m wondering, can i do transactions on my account using these recovery phrases? If so, how do i do it? I read it somewhere that the 12-word phrases is to recover your password in case you lost it , so I’m really hoping to recover my account!!!! please help !!!thank you everyone in advance

**update:**

I don't have the option to click on "recovery phrase". This is what Im seeing on my version, should I click on "export account"?

[image: account creation wizard]

UPDATE:

This is what I'm seeing right now after "restoring" my account. A new account "YUQI JIA" is created with 0.000 ETH and 0 SAN tokens in. The new account also had a complete different address. My tokens from the account I wanted to recover are still not transferrable. What do I do from here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, all is not lost!

When you create an account in Parity, or an Ethereum client, the private key and account details are stored encrypted in a keystore file on your hard drive. You enter the password to enable the decryption of the private key for the account in order to sign a transaction.

The [12 word mnemonic phrase](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mnemonic_phrase) is just a clever way to encode your private key in a more human-friendly way: it is in effect your private key and all you need to recover your account using Parity, MetaMask etc.

As per the [Parity documentation](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Backing-up-&-Restoring#restoring-options):

> In addition, it's possible to restore private keys from the 12-word mnemonic recovery phrase.

In Parity, you can click on the "Restore" option seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Which will give you a screen where you can enter the 12 words and enter a new password (to encrypt the subsequently generated keystore file):

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the steps necessary in the latest version of the Parity client.

Comment: I did what you said(click on restore on my version) ; however, it leads me to where I created another account with a different address and 0 token. Im still not able to transfer any of my tokens from the account that I've lost the password to the NEW account I created after I restore. I have put in the 12-word phrases and created a new password but it didn't change the fact the new account I created has 0 token inside. The tokens from my old account are still not transferable since the password is lost. The new account I've created is supposed to help me recover the old account right? but how?

Comment: I have a simpler solution - use MetaMask. I [recently answered a question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/30605/8469) that relates to importing accounts from the 12 words, but into MetaMask this time. You will need to [add the token manually](https://steemit.com/ico/@devender/how-to-add-etheruem-based-ico-tokens-in-metamask) for it to be visible in MetaMask. Hope that helps.